# Change directory of inactive pane of a remote instance of Vifm

Tags: client-server, vifm

Is there a way to change the directory of inactive pane using `--remote` argument in an existing instance of Vifm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via [`:winrun`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Awinrun) command or two argument form of [`:cd`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Acd) alone. Example:

```
# terminal #1
vifm --server-name test

# terminal #2
vifm --server-name test --remote +'winrun , cd /etc'
vifm --server-name test --remote +'cd . /etc'
```

Using `:cd` is simpler, but it will exit tree and custom views, so `:winrun` is preferable in general case, but `:cd` is more convenient for one off cases.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. A question: is it possible to also switch pane after this? So, basically, I want to update the inactive pane and then switch to it.

Comment: Yes, add `+'wincmd w'`. Could simplify to switch first and then cd: `+'wincmd w' +'cd /etc'`

Comment: ~ it doesn't work for me. `+'cd . /etc' +'wincmd w'` only changes the inactive pane. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was using an older version of vifm. This works in latest version. Thank you!